# Injected generic array doesn't contain any components

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

Code is taken [from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx). Unity should resolve all named registrations of `Account` type and put them into a generic array. But for some reason named `Account` dependencies are not resolved and thus the injected generic array is empty. Why is array not populated?

```
    container.RegisterType<Account>("first");
    container.RegisterInstance<Account>("second", new Account());

    container.RegisterType(
        typeof(MyClass<>),
        new InjectionConstructor(
            new GenericResolvedArrayParameter("T")));

    var myClass = container.Resolve<MyClass<Account>>();
    Console.WriteLine(myClass.InjectedValue.Length);   // 0

public class Account
{ }

public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T[] injectedValue;

    public MyClass(T[] injectedValue)
    {
        this.InjectedValue = injectedValue;
    }

    public T[] InjectedValue
    {
        get { return this.injectedValue; }
        set { this.injectedValue = value; }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Refrain from "begging bugs", especially in titles.

Comment: Why would/should the array have *any* size, much less *any* non-null values? That is, what rules above would let Unity know *what* to inject into the array?

Comment: @user2864740: If array of type Account[] is non-generic, then Unity creates an instance for each of registered Account types and injects them into that array. According to the link I've included, same thing should happen when array is generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using will just help Unity choosing a constructor that takes a single generic parameter `T`. However it does not tell which instances to provide.

You can use `GenericResolvedArrayParameter` to specify the named instances you want injected as in:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<Account>("first");
container.RegisterInstance<Account>("second", new Account());

container.RegisterType(
    typeof(MyClass<>),  
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new GenericResolvedArrayParameter(
            "T",
            new GenericParameter("T", "first"),
            new GenericParameter("T", "second"))));
```

However this is a bit cumbersome, and only really useful if you have multiple constructors (As you specify which constructor should Unity use) or if you just want to pass some of the named registrations (as you manually include them).  Luckily Unity understand arrays by default, and will provide all named instances. So **if you have a single constructor taking `T[]`** you don't need the registration for `MyClass` at all (as it is a concrete type):

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<Account>("first"); 
container.RegisterInstance<Account>("second", new Account());
var defaultInstance = new Account();
container.RegisterInstance<Account>(defaultInstance);
```

Just by doing that you could try to resolve `MyClass<Account>`, and you would see the named registrations "first" and "second" were injected.

```
var myClass = container.Resolve<MyClass<Account>>();
//myClass.injectedValue contains 2 items, from registrations "first" and "second"
//default (unnamed) registration is skipped
```

If instead of a constructor with an array parameter `T[]` you have another enumerable type like `IEnumerable<T>`, you can still use this last approach. Just add another registration that tells Unity how to map from arrays to the desired enumerable type:

```
container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<Account>,Account[]>();
```

I have created [this fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/doqWEU) testing the 4 approaches. 
Hopefully it will be useful to understand how these options work.

Comment: thanks. I didn't realize this code was only to demonstrate only how to choose a constructor. I thought it was also supposed to fill up the array with resolved named registrations. But then again, reading that article is like pulling teeth

Comment: Yes, that article is quite hard to follow! The msdn entries for [Unity 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170416.aspx) are somewhat better or at least easier to follow. I also forgot to mention that your initially code would also be useful if you only want to pass some of the named registrations into the array (I updated the answer to include that comment)